# Mediawiki API: get recent changes with categories of each page, or only those recentchanges entries which are in a certain category

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I want to retrieve from Mediawiki  the list of recent changes in a certain category. I am trying to use the recentchanges API; I would either need to be able to limit the results to that category, or for each recentchanges entry get the list of categories that page is in.

Comment: I tried to rewrite your question into something easier to understand. I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: What was wrong with my question? Now I read yours and it comes to me more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the list of changes in a specific category. To get the categories of each page, use the `recentchanges` API module as a generator: [action=query&generator=recentchanges&prop=categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=categories&generator=recentchanges)